# Asp Net Core 2.1 not listed in Visual Studio 2017 target framework

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I've installed [the new AspNet Core 2.1 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows) - which is now official - but it's still not listed in Visual Studio 2017 target framework, oin both existing projects and new projects:

[image: List]

As suggested in similar topics I've tried with:

- Installing both x64 and x32 versions of the SDK
- Installing the runtime separately
- Manually adding the installation path of the SDK to the environment variable `PATH`
- [Manually updating an existing project](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/migrate-existing-aspnet-core-2-application-aspnet-core-2-1/) (not worked because it wasn't able to find the 2.1 SDK)
- Restarting the PC
- Switching language between my native language (Italian) and English

But it's still not listed.

Reading VS infos, I got that Visual Studio version is 15.7.2 (latest) and NET framework version is 4.3.03056.

Executing `dotnet --info` from Powershell, i get this:
[image: version]

Does anyone know how to solve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Naming is totally confusing. You need to install the [2.1.300-rc1 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/sdk-2.1.300-rc1) to get .Net Core 2.1.

```
C:\>dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (gemäß "global.json"):
 Version:   2.1.300-rc1-008673
 Commit:    f5e3ddbe73

Laufzeitumgebung:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.16299
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300-rc1-008673\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.0-rc1
  Commit:  eb9bc92051

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.300-rc1-008673 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0-rc1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: I confirm that names are totally confusing... By the way thanks, it works!

Comment: This works however make sure you install the correct version according to your OS x64 or x86