# Upgrading an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application to ASP.NET Core 2.1 RC

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

Some days ago Microsoft announced .Net core 2.1 release candidate 1. [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/announcing-net-core-2-1-rc-1/]
[1]: 
How can I upgrade a .Net core2 project to 2.1 RC?

Comment: First of all you need to install the SDK or the [early access](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/2.1.0-Early-Access-Downloads) release (I suggest you the early access one).

Then, right click on your project on the right in visual studio 2017, go to settings and select the framework version from the dropdown and set asp net core 2.1. If you face any issue and the 2.1 is not listed, maybe you can find the solution on [this my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567218/asp-net-core-2-1-not-listed-in-visual-studio-2017-target-framework).

Comment: Also, give a look to [this](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/migrate-existing-aspnet-core-2-application-aspnet-core-2-1/) article. Hope it will help!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need the SDK installed ([available here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/sdk-2.1.300-rc1)). You'll also need to be running at least VS2017 15.7, but considering 2.1 is still a release candidate, I'd stick with VS2017 Preview for the time being ([available here](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/)).

Once you have all that, you simply need to edit your csproj file(s) and change the target framework to `netcoreapp2.1`.

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
```

The latest `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` NuGet package should then download automatically during the rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

There are several steps that should be taken to upgrade from ASP.NET Core 2.0 application to 2.1.

1. Change in the .csproj project file `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>`.
2. Replace the version specified **Microsoft.AspNetCore.All** package reference with the versionless **Microsoft.AspNetCore.App** package reference. You may need to add extra dependencies as several packages from *All* aren't included in the *App* package.
3. Remove all references to `<DotNetCliToolReference>` elements
4. In your *Startup.cs* change 

   `services.AddMvc();` to
   `services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);` (otherwise it defaults to 2.0)